# How to paste into google sheets with line break or newline a delimiter?

Tags: google-sheets

I copy some text from Notepad++ and paste it into google sheets. It pastes it tab-delimited. I want it to be pasted as new-line delimited. Tabs shouldn't be taken into account for delimiting.

I tried by deleting extra columns, keeping just one. but it creates extra columns. In excel there is an option to import text with a required delimiter. In Google sheets, how to achieve this? If there is no such thing, can it be achieved via app-script?

Comment: Please provide [mcve] or remove google apps script tag.  Were here to answer programming questions not general how to questions about Google Sheets.

Comment: Put cursor on the cell and press Enter. Tnen press Ctrl+V. Does it help?

Comment: @YuriKhristich, no, that is not my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case. Here is the little snippet that splits contents of selected cell by lines and puts these lines into bottom cells:

```
function split_cell() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var value = cell.getValue();
  var cells = value.split('\n').map(x => [x]);
  sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(),cell.getColumn(),cells.length).setValues(cells)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*If you want to import the text from the `txt` file, you can simply choose the delimiter you want.*

For instance, when using the **Import** option in Sheets:

[image: import option]

You can select a custom separator:

[image: custom delimiter]

However, if you are simply copying the text from the `txt` file, you may want to check the settings for the text editor you are using when it comes to the delimiter chosen.

#### Reference

- [Import data sets & spreadsheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/40608).

Comment: good point, but need to find a way to use a newline delimiter